# Octa-Core not Available in US

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Recently I was reviewing the Galaxy S7 Edge models, and noticed the Octa-Core is only available outside the US.

I realize the Octa-Core doesn't add much benefits, but it does have a certain "cool factor".

What reasons would prohibit the Octa-Core versions from entering the US? Surely radios and other country-specific components could be added/swapped to make a US Octa-Core version?

Comment: I'm curious why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumer preference, and media reviews, in the US have shown that any new top-tier Android phone has to have the latest and greatest Snapdragon to be considered worthy.  That may change as Samsung moves away from Android to their own Tizen OS, but the changes will probably have to show success outside the US first.